# Localhost redirected too many times

Tags: redirect, model-view-controller, controller, localhost, mapping

I am creating a spring mvc project. When i run it locally, I want the "home" view to be displayed,

```
 @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
```

however i get this error[local host redirected too many times error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIxZd.png) and this is the state of the network tab[network console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4U3T.png)
I have tried running it with cache disabled and in incognito but I get the same error. I have a security config as shown below.

```
@Bean(name = "mySecurityFilterChain")
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers(publicUrls()).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(login -> login
                        .loginPage("/login") // Custom login page
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate") // Custom login processing URL
                        .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                        //.defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard") // Redirect after successful login
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true") // Redirect after failed login
                        .permitAll())
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout") // Custom logout URL
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/home") // Redirect after successful logout
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll());
        
        return http.build();
    }

    private RequestMatcher publicUrls() {
        return new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/home"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/registersuccess")
        );
    }
```

Can anyone think of any reason why i would continue to be redirected to localhost:8081/login instead. I can provide any further necessary code if needed